# Reference ImageButton in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with two columns that have capability to be sorted. After its sorted I want to display an image next to a column with Arrow pointing up or down for Asc and Desc sort.

I cannot figure out how to reference an ImageButton object so I can set the ImageButton.ImageUrl to an actual image based on if its Asc and Desc.

Here is my .aspx code:

```
          <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
              <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Name_SortLnkBtn" runat="server" Text="Name:" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Name" CausesValidation="false" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Name_SortImgBtn" runat="server" Visible="false" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Name" CausesValidation="false" />
              </HeaderTemplate>                    
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/TestResults/Diabetes.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID") %>'><%#Eval("Name")%></asp:HyperLink>                                    
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
              <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="HouseName_SortLnkBtn" runat="server" Text="House Name:" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="House" CausesValidation="false" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="HouseName_SortImgBtn" runat="server" Visible="false" ToolTip="Click to Sort Column" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="House" CausesValidation="false" />
              </HeaderTemplate>                  
              <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("House")%></ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                 
          </Columns>
```

Help would be great appreciated.

Updated .aspx.cs file:

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected _code.SearchSelection _SearchSelection = new _code.SearchSelection();
    protected _code.Utils _utils = new _code.Utils();
    protected ImageButton sortImage = new ImageButton();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //if (!IsPostBack) {
        Master.FindControl("Home").ID = "active";
        GridView1_DataBind();
        //Guid ID = new Guid(_SearchSelection.getUserID().Tables[0].Rows[0]["u_ID"].ToString());             
        //}
    }

    protected void GridView1_DataBind() {
        string selection = string.Empty;
        TreeView treeMain = (TreeView)tree.FindControl("treeMain");
        if (treeMain.SelectedNode != null)
            selection = treeMain.SelectedNode.Text;
        else
            selection = Session["Selection"].ToString();
        DataSet mainData = _utils.getStoreProcedure(new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@Selection", selection) }, "sp_getTenantsWithDiabetes", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TIPS4"].ConnectionString);
        Session["MainData"] = mainData.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataSource = mainData.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e) {

        //Retrieve the table from the session object.
        DataTable dt = Session["MainData"] as DataTable;
        ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
        if (dt != null) {
            //Sort the data.
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
            //imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/Sugar2006/Images/arrow_up.gif";
            //imageButton.Visible = true;
            this.GridView1.DataSource = Session["MainData"];
            this.GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    private string GetSortDirection(string column) {

        // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
        string sortDirection = "ASC";

        // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null) {
            // Check if the same column is being sorted.
            // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
            if (sortExpression == column) {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC")) {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }

        // Save new values in ViewState.
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }

    protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) {                               
            var imageButton = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("Name_SortImgBtn");
            sortImage = imageButton;
            //imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/Sugar2006/Images/arrow_up.gif";
            //imageButton.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188689/change-sorting-image-button-in-gridview

Comment: Hey Thanks for reply. By looking at the link you provided that is when someone clicks on the actual image to sort but mine has the image not visible so I will not be able to send it to a Click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a reference to the `ImageButton` defined in your `HeaderTemplate`, you can wire up the [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event of the `GridView`. In the event handler, check if the row is the header row by using the `RowType` property, and then use the `FindControl` method to get a reference to the control.

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        var imageButton = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("Name_SortImgBtn");
        imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/myimage.gif";
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I think you're on the right track. I would make the following changes:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e) 
{
    //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    DataTable dt = Session["MainData"] as DataTable;
    if (dt == null) return;

    //Sort the data
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " +
                          GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
    this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    this.GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

There's no need to worry about the `ImageButton` in the `Sorting` event handler. The click of the `LinkButton` in the header will cause a post back, and the `Sorting` event handler will be called. It will run before the `RowDataBound` event is triggered (that won't happen until the `GridView1.DataBind` method is called). Also, the `GetSortDirection` method will store the sort expression and the sort order in the `ViewState`. We'll need those values later in the `RowDataBound` event handler (shown below).

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) 
    {
        //Determine sort column and sort order
        var column = ViewState["SortExpression"] != null ? 
                     ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString() : string.Empty;
        var sortDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] != null ? 
                     ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString() : string.Empty;

        //Find ImageButton based on sort column (return if not found)
        var imageButtonID = string.Concat(column, "_SortImgBtn");
        var imageButton = e.Row.FindControl(imageButtonID) as ImageButton;
        if(imageButton == null) return;

        //Determine sort image to display
        imageButton.ImageUrl = string.Equals("asc", sortDirection.ToLower()) ?
                               "~/App_Themes/Sugar2006/Images/arrow_up.gif" :
                               "~/App_Themes/Sugar2006/Images/arrow_down.gif";
        imageButton.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

In this event handler, we'll retrieve the values stored in the `ViewState` to determine which `ImageButton` to make `Visible` and which image url to use based on the sort direction. I made the assumption that you have given the `ImageButton` controls an `ID` of the column name plus `"_SortImgBtn"` (if you do things in this manner you can avoid a switch statement to map the column to the control name). Just make sure that the `ImageButton` controls have `Visible` set to `false` in the front page and the sorting image should be displayed.

Comment: That is a great example now do you know of a way getting it within an protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)

Comment: Because If I do it within the RowDataBound I will not be able to tell what sorting needs to be done.

Comment: Which event fires first? If Sorting fires before RowDataBound, then store the sort order in a private variable and update the ImageButton in RowDataBound. If RowDataBound fires first, then store the reference to the ImageButton in a private variable and update from Sorting.

Comment: Got it. The event that fires first is RowDataBound and then Sorting. But because there are currently two rows "Name" and "House Name" that can be sorted in the RowDataBound I will not know which one got clicked or any got clicked...

Comment: Check this MSDN example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx#Y400. Basically they're storing the sort expression and direction in the ViewState, and then calling DataBind after changing the sorting on the data source. If you use that approach, then you can pull those values out of the ViewState in the RowDataBound event handler to find and set the ImageButtons properly. If you post more of your code I can whip up a better example.

Comment: I used a very similar approach for my program. I placed the .aspx.cs code above to my original posting. Take a look at let me know if that makes sense to you. I really really appreciate you taking your time to help out with this.